# PHP Send multiple rows in one mail with if statement

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm sending a reminder mail with values from an `mysql db`. I'm sending the mail one day before the appointment with an if statement. The problem is that I'm sending a mail for each row and I want a summary of all the data in one mail. I already tried to put the **if statement outside the while loop**, but then I only got the first result of `mysqldb` and I need them all.

My code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM moments"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){              
    $name= $row['name'];    
    if($difference == -1) {  //$difference is my calculation for the day before, it works so I'm not writing it down                
        $to = 'mail@mail.com';
        $message = $name;
        $subject = 'This is the subject';

        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

        // Mail it
        mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));               
    }   
}
```

Comment: You want all names in a single mail..?

Comment: Everything that should be executed only once belongs outside the loop.

Comment: Add to `$name` like `$name .= $row['name'];` and send the mail outside of the `while`.

Comment: This is great, I forgot about 'concatenate'. Everything works now. Thank you for the solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM moments"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$summary = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){               
    $summary[] = $row; 
}   
//var_dump($summary);
```

`$summary` will contain those results as **array format** if you're referring data for `contacts`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send one mail that contains all the data, you need to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) all the data. Something like this would work:

```
$name = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{               
    $name .= $row['name'] . "\n";
}
```

After this you can just send `$name` formatted however you wish.

Another option would be to put all the results in an array and then [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them, like so:

```
$names = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{               
    $names[] = $row['name'];
}
$message = "The names are: " . implode(', ', $names);
```

The above syntax will create a comma-separated list of names.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the message and send it in one email as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM moments"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$message = ''; // Initialize the message to blank

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{               
    $name= $row['name'];

    if($difference == -1) {  //$difference is my calculation for the day before, it works so I'm not writing it down

        $message .= $name . '<br/>';

    }
}

// Send email if message is present
if(!empty($message))
{
    $to = 'mail@mail.com';

    $subject = 'This is the subject';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as following

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM moments"; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $message = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {               
        $name= $row['name'];

    if($difference == -1) {  //$difference is my calculation for the day before, it works so I'm not writing it down

    $to = 'mail@mail.com';

    $message = $message."<br>".$name;

    $subject = 'This is the subject';

        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

        // Mail it


    }   
}
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Comment: This will still send multiple emails. OP needs only one email to be sent.